# Spring boot end point to find particular record

Tags: java, spring-boot, endpoint

I am working on creating test end points in spring boot service.

I have one end point, that works well.
Here is the working end point code:

```
Controller:

@GetMapping("/searchAll")
        public List<MyData> searchAll() {
   
            List<MyData> dataList = myServiceDAO.findAll();
            return dataList;
         }
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
public class MyServiceDAO {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<MyData> findAll()
    {
        return jdbctemplate.query("SELECT * FROM demooutput", new DataRowMapper());
    }
```

I need to have another end point which find data only for particular member: I am trying to implement this end point, but it doesn't get details.
Here is the code, that's not working.

```
@GetMapping("/searchDataByMember/{memberno}")
        public List<MyData> searchDataByMember(int memberno) {
    
            List<MyData> dataList = myServiceDAO.findDataByMemberNo(memberno);
            return dataList;
        }
```

DAO:

```
@Repository
public class MyServiceDAO {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<MyData> findAll()
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM demooutput";
        return jdbctemplate.query("SELECT * FROM demooutput", new DataRowMapper());
    }
    // This is not working
    public List<MyData> findDataByMemberNo(int memberno)
    {
        return jdbctemplate.query("SELECT member_no, dt, name, drnumber, docid, contact FROM demooutput where member_no=memberno?", new DataRowMapper());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @PathVariable:

```
@GetMapping("/searchDataByMember/{memberno}")
public List<MyData> searchDataByMember(@PathVariable Integer memberno) {

    List<MyData> dataList = myServiceDAO.findDataByMemberNo(memberno);
    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. "jdbctemplate.query" part is correct?

Comment: But, we are not passing "member_no" value here in the query, right?

Comment: return jdbctemplate.query("SELECT * FROM demooutput where member_no=?", new Object[]{memberno}, new DataRowMapper());
Try this variant